# JPA How to map plist array to entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm new in hibernate/jpa, and now strugling with next question:

I have a column A1 in Table A, which holds a String which is an ASCII-plist array of numbers :

```
"(1,2,4,56)"
```

Numbers are ids of Objects from Table B
It is so weird(and I don't like this) due to some historical reasons, and can't be refactored.

Question.
What is the easist way to get something like this :

```
private List<B> A1;
```

Now I'm able only to get a List of Strings using converter

```
@Column(name = "A1")
@Convert(converter = NSArrayConverter.class)
private List<String> A1;
```

Only suggestion I have now, is in converter make fetches of B records, based on decoded plist... But maybe there is a better solution?

Comment: What DB are you using? You could theoretically do something like `@JoinTable(name = "LATERAL UNNEST(string_to_array(substr(column, 1, length(column) - 1), ','))")` or `@JoinTable(name = "STRING_SPLIT(substr(column, 1, length(column) - 1), ',')")`. Highly depends on your DBMS regarding splitting the string into an array or rows directly.

Comment: @ChristianBeikov DB is Postgres, but I got your idea. Will try. Thanks

Comment: Would be nice if you could get back to me and tell me if it worked. Never tried that myself before so I'd like to know :)

Comment: @ChristianBeikov Yep. That works, with small changes:

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.DETACH)

    @JoinTable(name = "(SELECT A_ID as A_A_ID,unnest(string_to_array(substring(coalesce(COLUMN, '{}') from 2 for length(coalesce(COLUMN, '{}'))-2), ', ')::int[]) as A_B_ID FROM A)", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "A_A_ID", referencedColumnName = "A_ID"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "A_B_ID", referencedColumnName = "B_ID"))